# React is not rendering data from another component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks

I have created below code under `button`. It is inside `table body`.

```
                              <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onClick={()=>popUp()} > 
                                        
                                        {flag &&  (   
                                                <div >
                                                   <table className="table table-responsive"   <tr><td className="bg-primary">Certificate No</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.certificateNo}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">Sponsor</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.sponser}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">Protocol No</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.protoColNo}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">Start Date</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.startDate}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">End Date</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.endDate}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">No Of Subjects</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">Country</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.country}</td></tr>
                                                       <tr><td className="bg-primary">Request Status</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.requestStatus}</td></tr>
                                                       
                                                   </table>
                                                </div>   
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                            )}
                                            <i className="bi bi-search">
                                                 
                                            </i>
                                        </button>
```

the above data is part of table in a particular component.

Now when I tried to write the same code in another component it is printing only static data but it is not rendering result.

```
import React from 'react'

const TablePopup = (certificate:any) => {
    return (
        <div className="popup-box">
        <div className=" container box">
        <span className="close-icon" >x</span>    
        <div >
           <table className="table table-responsive" >

               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Certificate No</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.certificateNo}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Sponsor</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.sponser}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Protocol No</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.protoColNo}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Start Date</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.startDate}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">End Date</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.endDate}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">No Of Subjects</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.noOfSubjects}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Country</td><td  className="bg-success">{certificate.country}</td></tr>
               <tr><td className="bg-primary">Request Status</td><td className="bg-success">{certificate.requestStatus}</td></tr>
               
           </table>
        </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TablePopup
```

and I called this `App` by writing

```
  <TablePopup certificate={certificate}/>
```

`certificate` is array variable.  `response.map((certificate: Certificate,index:number) => {`

Comment: you should loop over `certificate` inside `table` tag like:  `<table>{certificate.map( (certifcate) => {<tr><td .....})}</table>`

Comment: Change the curly braces in your .map to parentheses. {response.map((certificate: Certificate,index:number) => (...))}

Comment: @Alan on the same component is rendering data. I am trying to pass same data to another component and using that component just for clean code

Answer (score 0):

According to me the certificate props should be destructured in TablePopup component like this to use it in component or use props.certifcate

const TablePopup = ({certificate: any}) => {}